# Difficulty with getting visual studio 2013 on my laptop

Tags: visual-studio

Can someone teach me how to download visual studio 2013 on  windows 10 laptop? I kept on trying to get it from the official website but jus keeps downloading visual studio 2015 for me. Sorry if this is a stupid questuon, but I am a noob.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link for the vs2013 express iso.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44914

Comment: Thanks. Agree with OP that MS does make it difficult to find older versions of VS community edition.